# Java, passing database connection into different classes.

Tags: java, database, db2, database-connection

I don't understand the purpose of ***DatabaseAccess*** class. I'm curious about how did the object name **"conDA"** contains the database connection even without using the **getConnection()** method I created. Example **"con2 = new Connection2(conDA);"** how is that "conDA" object name can be understood as a connection of database? 
Here are the codes:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Connection1 
{
    static Connection connection;
    static ConnectionDA conDA;
    static Connection2 con2;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        conDA = new ConnectionDA(getConnection());
        System.out.println("Con1 Connected!!");
        con2 = new Connection2(conDA);  
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/Sample", "ZeroCool","siliconvalley"); 

        return connection;
    }
}
```

2nd Class

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Connection2
{
    ConnectionDA conDA;
    Connection3 con3;

    public Connection2(ConnectionDA conDA) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        this.conDA = new ConnectionDA(conDA.getConnection());
        this.conDA = conDA;
        System.out.println("Con2 Connected!!");
        con3 = new Connection3(conDA);
    }
}
```

3rd Class

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Connection3 
{
    ConnectionDA conDA;

    public Connection3(ConnectionDA conDA) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        this.conDA = new ConnectionDA(conDA.getConnection());
        this.conDA = conDA;
        System.out.println("Con3 Connected!!");
    }
}
```

Database Access Class

```
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectionDA 
{
    Connection connection;

    public ConnectionDA(Connection connection) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        this.connection = connection;
        System.out.println("ConDA Established!!!");
    }

    public Connection getConnection() 
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is that "conDA" object name can be understood as a connection of
>   database?

because the class ConnectionDA have the method getConnection implement that returns an object of the type connection.

```
public Connection3(ConnectionDA conDA) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    this.conDA = new ConnectionDA(conDA.getConnection());
}
```

And here the implementation of the getConnection() method.

```
public class ConnectionDA 
{
    public Connection getConnection() 
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

> I'm curious about how did the object name "conDA" contains the
>   database connection even without using the getConnection() method I
>   created

this is because, the class receive an connection on the constructor

```
public class ConnectionDA 
{
    Connection connection;

    public ConnectionDA(Connection connection) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, I just need to call the ConnectionDA  to establish connection to other classes? If that's the case, what is the use of getConnection() method everytime I initialize a conDA object name?

Comment: you have the method getConection() to get the connection in the case you need it for some reason.